# Tokenizing array of strings in powershell

Tags: powershell, powercli

I use this code to retrieve the list of VMs from vSphere.

```
[string]$arrayVM = (Get-VM | Select-Object -Property Name).Name
Write-Host($arrayVM)
```

It is fine as I get the following output

```
N1.windows1 N2.linux1 N3.linux2
```

However, then I use `Write-Host($arrayVM[0])`, I get `N`. I would like to get `N1.windows1`. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first line, you coerce the value to type `string`. That’s why `$arrayVM` is not an array at all (except in the sense that a string is a character array).

Instead, the first line should read as follows (provided your PS version is new enough):

```
[string[]]$arrayVM = (Get-VM).Name
```

Comment: What's the minimum version of PS required for this to work?

Comment: @spikey_richie According to [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24938623/1025421) you need at least PowerShell 3. Otherwise, it’s back to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`, `% { $_.Name }` or the like.